# How do I use Maven as a sane build system?

Tags: java, maven

Yes, this is a real question.

I want to cater for the following workflow in a multi module Maven based project:

- Make a change in module X
- Run a Java application in module Y

Module Y may directly or indirectly depend on module X, I need all modules affected by a change to another to be compiled, recursively. I do not want tests to be run.

How, in Maven, do I do this without having to compile and install everything every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Development stage**

I don't think you could do it easily with the maven only. During development however you could skip tests adding `-DskipTests`.

The maven cannot do incremental compilation properly. The right way to do it is to use IDE which will import maven projects into IDE's projects and then you could have fast and easy development. IntelliJ IDEA works quite well with the maven.

**Production stage**

For release build you could use explicit versions in the target artifact. So after changes in module X if you building the final release artifact module Y you could add explicit dependency in it. In this case all modules between X and Y will have older version (but you should assume they will work with the new X which is always not true).

Comment: The thing that makes maven difficult isn't the incremental building, its that maven will not go UP a hierarchy for build dependencies. That's why its best to do -amd -pl at the top level.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell The point is not to use maven commands, but use IDE, for development it is the best, mvn is too slow even with these magic parameters. For production it doesn't matter, because it is CI's headache.

Comment: +1 for use an IDE, I just feel dirty building with two different methods. Visual Studio / MSBuild anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have to make and install everytime? The easiest solution I've found is `mvn install` one time. Then you can go into individual projects and build them whenever you want. If you need to ensure the chain is picked up just do the build from the top and use `mvn -amd -pl projectname`

This says to build a specific project and it's dependencies.

Comment: Great answer. That's exactly what most Continues Integration solutions do when build on SCM change (without `clean`). Projects list for `-pl` parameter results from SCM changes.